# Facebook send request shows me the store empty, I'm testing the Android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Facebook - Android App that use the request of facebook. When I create the code I put a message in the request params to send, but this is not showing in the request when see this in FaceBook app for Android.
Then I click over the Facebook notification but redirect to the playstore, play return an empty app because I'm testing the app and there is no upload into Google Play.
The question is if I have to upload my App to Google Play for test the requests (for send and detect the incoming request).

The Facebook code I'm using is the same that the code on the Facebook send request tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/send-requests/

Thank you very much.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I did not put the correct package in the Facebook App.

Thanks!